# How to achieve ChatGPT like refresh of tableview on response? iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, xml-parsing, tableview, chat, openai-api

I am building chat app that is using XMPP and ChatGPT with knowledge base. Current setup of XMPP that is returning xml in a stream, so that means sometimes I am getting a single word, sometimes a few characters of a word and sometimes even just spacing. Actually, for a sentence of a 20 words, lets say I get 50 times a response in a stream. If I reload tableview each time, my UI is blocking, how to achieve seamless reload of data and show a response each time like ChatGPT app?

Comment: You need more detail in your question.  How are you showing the result?  Is each word a cell in your table or is the response shown in one cell?  You could use a `Timer` to reload the table/cell a second or so after a response is received.  If you get another response before the timer fires, restart the timer.  You can do the same sort of thing with `Combine` too.

Comment: Currently I am showing everything in tableview, and refreshing tableview on every notification of response. I am using datasource to prepare data for tableview. This is a chat app, so no, I am not showing each response in a separate cell. Once stream ends, I show that response in a single cell.

Currently I am trying to delay refresh of a tableview with a throttle which is set to 0.5 seconds, but its not helping.

If I set it to a second, then its not looking good from side of UX. It doesn't look fluently.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to show the code.

Answer (score 0):

Reload the uitableviewcell (The cell to which you want to update the text), not the entire table view.

```
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(paths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
```